# Is it possible delete entity from DB and then return this value in JpaRepository?

Tags: java, database, spring, jpa

So I want after deleting my entity return object up to Controller in next way:

```
@Transactional
Author deleteByAuthorId(long authorId);
```

But I get an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to ua.com.epam.entity.Author
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible as the underlying API used by spring JPA is `PreparedStatement#executeUpdate` which returns the number of the row it has deleted.

Comment: And this is no way to do this?

Comment: I don't believe there is an inbuilt way to do that.  However, you can write your own API to that.

Comment: I just do it) Ok, than question: is it be good if before deleting (if entity with current id exists, of course) I will get it to object and after deleting will return this getted object?

Comment: @RomanShmandrovskyi I believe it is not good practice. You may face an issue with JPA session.